# Problem booting Ubuntu Server after editing /etc/fstab to mount secondary hdd

Tags: 12.04, fstab, mountpoint

I have added a secondary hdd to my server and modified the /etc/fstab with the line

```
UUID=1579e689-3965-47db-83a7-665cceeb6aff /media/storage ext4 defaults 0 0
```

but now when I am rebooting the server it is around 15 minutes it is still in progress. Should I wait longer as the secondary hdd has lot of data in it and that could be the reason for longer boot time.

Please suggest if I have done it right or some thing wrong with the modificaation?

Comment: You set the last field to 0, which means a fsck on reboot would not happen. Did you try to run `mount -a` after the modification to see if things were all right?

Comment: Hi Josip Rodin - `mount -a`  works perfect. what could be the reason for halt on boot.

Comment: Hard to say without any error messages. Can you please include the boot log in your question or at least a picture of the boot console?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was resolved. How far this is correct I am not sure, but I resolved it like this.
I was not creating the mount point that /media/storage and adding the line to /etc/fstab
The directory `storage` was automatically being created in /media/ and on manual mount it was working fine.

But I read somewhere that you have to create the mount point with root privileges so I deleted the `storage` directory and created another directory with the command
`sudo mkdir /media/server-backup` and modified the /etc/fstab accordingly.

Then I rebooted the machine and I didn't face any problem the secondary hdd was mounted without any problem.